# How can I solve this case with Java generics?

Tags: java, generics

I have a key value pairs stored in a Map as: `Map<String, Object>`. The values are fetched from a file and belong to different primitives, hence stored as Object type in the Map.

Suppose the Map contains three key value pairs as:

```
{
    "objA": 1,
    "objB": "MyName",
    "obj3": "19-09-2015"
}
```

ObjA has to be retrieved as Integer, objB has to be retrieved as String and obj3 has to be retrieved as LocalDate.

I want to have a single method in which I pass the Map, KeyName and Desired Class as arguments and it should return the fetched value with Desired Class as the type:

Something like this:

```
public T fetch(Map<String, Object> myMap, String key, Class T) {
    // Find value corresponding to 'key' 
    Object object = myMap.get(key);

    // Return the object as type T
    return (T)object; 
}
```

Then I would call this method like:

```
Double myJavaValue = fetch(myMap, myValue, java.lang.double.class);
```

How exactly can I achieve this?

Comment: Thanks everyone. Answers by laune, weston, shengbo.zhao, alex served the purpose. Could accept only one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The full method would be:

```
public <T> T fetch(Map<String, Object> myMap, String key, Class<T> clazz) {
    // Find value corresponding to 'key' 
    Object object = myMap.get(key);
    return clazz.cast(object); 
}
```

Answer (score 4):

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public static <T> T fetch(Map<String, Object> myMap, String key) {
    return (T) myMap.get(key);
}
```

Comment: Might not compile depending on warnings/flags. You'll get an unchecked cast warning, but should compile fine. This has the added benefit of working based on the context it's used and not requiring the third parameter.

Comment: Try to call your "fetch" in a println. Very iffy, to rely on the context. I would not recommend it.

Comment: @laune works fine in a `println`, because the context is then object.

Comment: Did you actually try it?

Comment: @laune yeah, did you?

Comment: @laune and weston, I do not get warning when I use .cast method, but get warning when casting normally like (T) myMap.getKey(key). Why is this difference?

Comment: Z.java:37: error: reference to println is ambiguous
 System.out.println( fetch(map,"xxx") );
  both method println(char[]) in PrintStream and method println(String) in PrintStream match

Comment: @AnmolGupta Because calling method cast isn't a "cast" that is covered by these warnings. It is assumed that you know the risk (ClassCastException at runtime) when you call it.

Comment: @weston And another one: try  `int i = 13 +  fetch(map,"xxx");` There are several contexts where the result class of your version cannot be established.

Comment: It's definitely safest to be explicit, as @laune mentions (and their corresponding answer fits the explicit scenario). This signature is a valid solution that may be an acceptable API depending on how it's called and an interesting alternative.

Comment: @laune re:println I was compiling against 1.5! Yeah it's a problem for later ones.

Comment: There's nothing unsafe about this. The context is still fixed at compile time, and often when it's ambiguous it doesn't even compile. Any ambiguity can be avoided by a local or parameter variable or cast. The runtime exception from this cast failing is the same as the one from `class.cast`. Any other problems will be shown up by the extensive test suite we all have right?!

Comment: Just boils down to would you rather write: `int i = 13 + (int)fetch(map,"xxx")` just when it's ambiguous, or `int i = 13 + fetch(map,"xxx", int.class)` all the time.

Answer (score 1):

```
public static <T>  T func(MapM<String, T> myMap, String key, Class<T> cls) {
    return cls.cast(myMap.get(key));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
private void start() {
    Map<String, Object> dataMap = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    dataMap.put("objA", 1);
    dataMap.put("objB", "MyName");
    dataMap.put("objC", LocalDate.of(2015, 9, 19));

    this.fetch(dataMap, "objA", Integer.class);
    this.fetch(dataMap, "objB", String.class);
    this.fetch(dataMap, "objC", LocalDate.class);
}

private <T> T fetch(Map<String, Object> myMap, String key, Class<T> dataType) {
    return dataType.cast(myMap.get(key));
}
```

Comment: BTW, `cast` will return `null` if a `null` is passed into it, so the `containsKey` check shouldn't be necessary.

Comment: got it thx.  @return the object after casting, or null if obj is null

Comment: Using T as a parameter name and a generic parameter name is bad style.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the cast method.

```
return T.cast(myValue);
```

Comment: Without supplying all the rechnical details your answer is insufficient.